# How to get push all the matches in the string for a regex expression in to some collection

Tags: c#, regex

I had some regex in which i have to capture all the matches in the string and push them to some collection and have iterate through the matches to do some stuff.

```
 Regex regx = new Regex(@"{{\w+}}");

            Match m = regx.Match(str);

            string sel = m.Value;
            string actualProp = sel.Substring(2, sel.Length - 4);

            str = Regex.Replace(str, actualProp, x);
```

i had the Ex: string : the {{name}} is {{name.child}}

so i have to get all the two matches in to collection, i couldn't figure out how any work around plz.....

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Matches` method of `Regex` and iterate through the results, see this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3.aspx

**[Edit]**
Then to access the [groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx) within a match (by index or named group):

```
Regex regex = new Regex("pattern");
foreach(Match match in regex.Matches("input"))
{
    string val = match.Groups[1].Value;
    string val2 = match.Groups["group_name"].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Match m = regx.Match(str);
    var results = new List<string>();
    while (m.Success)
    {
        results.Add(m.Value);
        m = m.NextMatch();
    }
```